# How to import using React.lazy using absolute path?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I can do

```
import Main from 'components/main'
```

I can do that because I have the following in `config-overrides.js` (which actually overrides webpack config)

```
const resolveModules = () => (config) => {
  config.resolve = Object.assign({}, config.resolve, {
    modules: [
      resolveApp('src'),
      resolveApp('src_copied'),
      resolveApp('node_modules'),
    ],
    extensions: ['.js', '.ios.js', '.android.js', '.native.js'],
  })
  return config
}
```

Now I want to do the following

```
const Main = React.lazy(() => import('components/main'))
```

But it fails to import the file.

So how do I correctly lazy import a file using an absoute path?

Comment: I have the same problem and the same need. Have you found a solution?